# Django TypeError:"User" object is not iterable pops up during serialization

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem with my django project. Im using django rest framework and seems like im doing something wrong during serialization. So here is the issue:

I have an APIview that should return a JSON to the user that should be auth by token. This json should contain the list of users classes for today.here is the code:

```
class StudentTodayScheduleView(views.APIView):
    """
    API that returns JSON with schedule for user who is requesting
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        usergroup = ProfileModel.objects.filter(user=user)[0].student_group
        current_weekday = datetime.date.today().weekday()  # integer 0-monday .. 6-Sunday
        today = WorkingDay.objects.get(dayoftheweeknumber=current_weekday)

        todaysdate = datetime.date.today()
        weektype = get_weektype(todaysdate)

        classes_for_today = Para.objects.filter(para_group=usergroup, para_day=today, week_type=weektype)
        result = dict()
        for para in classes_for_today:
                result.update(ParaSerializer(para).data)

        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the ParaSerializer:

```
class ParaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    para_subject = DisciplineSerializer()
    para_room = RoomSerializer()
    para_professor = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    para_number = ParaTimeSerializer()
    para_day = WorkingDaySerializer()
    # para_group = StudentGroupSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Para
        fields = (
            'para_subject',
            'para_room',
            'para_professor', 
            'para_number',
            'para_day',
            'para_group',
            'week_type'
    )
```

here is what console shows:
[image]

ProfileModel its the additional model that gets added to the default django User model. ProfileModel has OneToOneField with User.

If i try to serialize Para object in shell - its ok. But if I try to get out data out of the serialized para object - i would get the same error that you see on the screenshot.
Also if i comment out para_professor field in the serializer class - i would not get an error.

Please explain what i'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your time
Taras

UPDATE:

Para model, User and Profile serializers:

```
class Para(models.Model):

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = u"Class"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Classes"

    para_subject = models.ForeignKey(
        'Disciplines',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Discipline"
    )
    para_room = models.ForeignKey(
        'Rooms',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Room"
    )
    para_professor = models.ForeignKey(
        'students.ProfileModel',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Professor"
    )
    para_number = models.ForeignKey(
        'ParaTime',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Class Starts/Ends"
    )
    para_day = models.ForeignKey(
        WorkingDay,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Working day")

    para_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'StudentGroupModel',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=u"Student Group"
    )
    week_type = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        verbose_name=u"Is week even"
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.para_subject, self.para_room)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'groups',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileModel
        fields = (
            'user',
            'is_student',
            'student_group',
            'middle_name',
            'contact_phone',
            'photo',
            'started_date'
        )
```

Comment: You should probably show your model definition, and also the code for UserSerializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ProfileSerializer defines `user` with `many=True`, but there is only one user per profile.